# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Environment'

Tags: python, caffe, lmdb

I am trying convert jpeg files to 'lmdb' format. But I got this error:

```
>>> import lmdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lmdb.py", line 25, in <module>
    write_images_to_lmdb('/home/anaca/ferjpg' , 'fer2013')
  File "lmdb.py", line 13, in write_images_to_lmdb
    env = lmdb.Environment(db_name, map_size=map_size)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Environment'
```

Things that I try :

```
 pip install lmdb
 sudo apt-get install liblmdv-dev
```

Here's the code:

```
import caffe
import lmdb
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
from caffe.io import datum_to_array, array_to_datum
def write_images_to_lmdb(img_dir, db_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img_dir, topdown = False):
        if root != img_dir:
            continue
        map_size = 64*64*3*2*len(files)
        env = lmdb.Environment(db_name, map_size=map_size)
        txn = env.begin(write=True,buffers=True)
        for idx, name in enumerate(files):
            X = mp.imread(os.path.join(root, name))
            y = 1
            datum = array_to_datum(X,y)
            str_id = '{:08}'.format(idx)
            txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())   
    txn.commit()
    env.close()
    print " ".join(["Writing to", db_name, "done!"])

write_images_to_lmdb('/home/anaca/ferjpg' , 'fer2013')
```

Comment: which version of python are you using? are you using a virtualenv? which version of pip?

Answer (score 1):

From your traceback it seems as if the script you are trying to run is named `lmdb.py`.  Change its name to something else.

Otherwise, when Python sees `import lmdb` it assumes you mean your script rather than the `lmdb` module you have installed.